# best fraction algorithm

Tags: algorithms

So i have 7 "fractions" that i need to build a algorithm for.

a/16 b/15 c/15 d/14 e/10 f/8 g/3 are the "fractions"(the denominators will never change) now when you add all the denominators together and then you add all the numerators together you will get (a + b + c + d + e + f + g)/(16 + 15 + 15 + 14 + 10 + 8 + 3).

From this we get a percentage. Now i need to select the best 5"fractions" of the 7"fractions" that will result with me with the best percentage at the end. so i cant just work them out individually and pick the best 5.

Example: if i got 8.74/14 and 5/8 so 62.42% and 62.5% respectively the 5/8 would be selected and the end result would be 5+(the other 4 numerators) / 8+(the other 4 denominators) this gives me a 70%. where if i got 9.74/14 a 69.57% then it would be picked so that when i add those numbers to the other 4 numerators and denominators the end percentage is 68% so even though i got a better mark on one test the end percentage is less because the denominator grew. so 5 out of 7 that add up to the best.

what i was thinking is taking all the "fractions" with the smallest denominators and arrange them against the ones the ones with the biggest numerators so that you end up with the biggest possible numerator with the smallest possible denominator possible.

i am sorry that i struggle to express myself i hope that makes sense. i need to eventually turn this into ruby haha.

can anyone express this in an equation? i am not very good at math and this has fried my brain.

Comment: This sounds like a pure algorithmic/math question. Did you really intend to ask it on a *Mathematica* site? If so, please clarify how you expect to use *Mathematica* for the solution.

Comment: "i need to eventually turn this into Ruby haha." - I'm sending you to math.SE for the time being.

Comment: Please use MathJax to make the fractions clearer

Answer (score 1):

Consider this answer as temporary. The solution is kind of specific for Mathematica, from which this question was moved, so maybe using loops or something would have made it easier to see a Ruby solution. Anyway, this is what I typed. Mods can delete if they want.

----mathematica answer ----

Quickly, before it gets moved! (too late :( )

Note that this is just brute force as there are only 21 = Binomial[7,2]= 7 choose 2 possibilities.

```
nnnn = 7;

denoms = {16, 15, 15, 14, 10, 8, 3};
denomTotal = Total[denoms];

Clear[f]
Evaluate[Array[f[#] &, nnnn]] = list = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, nnnn]
value[ints_] := Total[Delete[list, List /@ ints]]/denomTotal


possibilities = 
  Array[Function[xxxx, 
    Delete[#, 0] &@Array[{xxxx, #} &, 7 - xxxx, xxxx + 1]], 7];


Length@possibilities == Binomial[7, 2]


values =
 value /@ possibilities


Max@values // N
```